# How to improve speed of a loop where conditionally defining vector?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, vectorization

I have the following chunk of code where I am creating a vector inside a for loop conditional on other vectors and a data frame. I am iterating approximately 15,000 times and need to run this code a lot (100s of times). Right now it is very slow so I am trying to make it faster. I realize it is probably very inefficient to be using which() at each iteration of the loop but I am not sure how to change this. I have thought of using the apply() functions but am not sure they will help make things faster. I've also been thinking about vectorizing instead of running the for loop. Thanks a lot for your time and your help in advance!

Here is the an example data frame `temp_dat`:

```
   MONTH             ID  E
1      9 19951100023401 32
2      7 19951100023401 32
3      9 19951100023402 34
4      7 19951100023402 34
5      9 19951100023403 32
6      7 19951100023403 32
7      9 19951100023903 90
8      7 19951100023903 79
9      9 19951100024403 34
10     7 19951100024403 34
```

The code I am running is:

```
vector1 <- c()
x<- unique(temp_dat$ID)
for (a in 1:length(x)) {
  b = x[a]
  
  vector1[a] <- as.numeric(((temp_dat[which(temp_dat$ID == b & temp_dat$MONTH == 9),]$E %in% c(90,97)) & (temp_dat[which(temp_dat$ID == b & temp_dat$MONTH == 7),]$E %in% c(79,77))))
}
```

which has as output vector1 with values

`0 0 0 1 0`

Comment: It would help if we knew what `temp_date` is and what you want the final output to look like

Comment: `temp_dat` is just a data frame. In terms of output, I am using the vectors vector1-3_final for something outside of the loop.

Comment: Please edit the question with example input and output so we can play with it

Comment: Read [MCVE]. You are NOT being asked to provide your entire dataset, only enough data to do some testing and allow comparison with what you think should be the answer when run with that example. And do read [edit]. You seem to be ignoring comments about how your question violates the norms for posting here. That's what getting you downvotes (and no answer.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the suggestions. I just added an example with the desired output. I apologize in advance if I didn't properly share the data frame in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require(data.table)
temp_dat <- as.data.table(temp_dat)
temp_dat[,
         as.integer(
           any(MONTH == 9 & (E %in% c(90,97))) &&
             any(MONTH == 7 & (E %in% c(79,77)))
           ),
         by = ID]$V1
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try it out and test the performance